# nginx+nginx-rtmp-moduleの中でffmpegを動かすが動いていない様子の対応法

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, nginx-rtmp-module

nginx+nginx-rtmp-moduleの中でffmpegを動かそうとしています。テストnginx.confとして以下のように記載しました。

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
    access_log logs/rtmp_access.log;
    chunk_size 4096;
    timeout 10s;
        application live {
            live on;
            #interleave on;
            record off;
        exec /usr/sbin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/4k -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/2klive/stream;
        }
    application 2klive {
            live on;
            #interleave on;
            record off;
        # HLS配信設定
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
        hls_fragment 10s;
        }
    }
}
```

別のサーバからrtmp://<nginxサーバIP>/live/4kに映像をffmpegで送っていて、このffmpegは正常に動いているようです。

しかし、ffmpegが動いていない模様

```
# ps aux | grep ffmpeg
　・・・何も出ない
```

そして、stream.m3u8もどこにも生成されていません。

```
# find / -name stream.m3u8 -print
　・・・何も出ない
```

なお、nginxのサーバにffmpegのパスは通っています。

```
# which ffmpeg
/usr/sbin/ffmpeg
```

## 失礼しました。↑パスコピペミスです。修正しました。

こちら対処法をご存知の方は教えてください。

Comment: ffmpegのパスが確認できているなら、まずはnginx.confにそちらのパスを指定するところからしてみたほうが良いかなとは思います。（現在のconfのパスも正しいのかもしれないですが）